# Expiration date for http only cookie with JWT token

Tags: authentication, http, cookies, jwt, access-token

While implementing `JWT` authorization, I encountered questions to which I couldn't find an answers, so I'm asking for your help!

### **Context**:

I have **access/refresh** tokens that are passed to the client as **http-only** cookies. The access token lives for 20 minutes and the refresh token for 30 days. On the server, I validate the token lifetimes.

### **Questions**:

What role does the cookie lifespan play?

Can I set them to be infinite, and would this not contradict security principles?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a token in a cookie that is expired, the string *should* be useless so there's no risk. On the other hand, I don't see why you wouldnt just expire the cookie at the same time as the token. Also obligatory: https://evertpot.com/jwt-is-a-bad-default/